# Call a webapi from another web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to call a web api from a web api. For some reason after the line where i call await client.PostAsJsonAsync(), nothing happening. When i did the call from a console applicaiton i get the response without any issue. NOt sure what is the problem. Please let me know what i am doing wrong here.

here is my code

```
private async Task RunAsync()
{
    const string apiBaseAddress = "http://localhost/ExternalAPI/";
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var vendRequest = new CustomRequest
    {
        XX = "xx",
        YY = 1,
        ZZ = 12.50M
    };

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(apiBaseAddress + "Purchase/1", vendRequest);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        string error = "1";
    }
}
```

Comment: So open the developer console and see what's happening with the request.

Comment: what do you mean by "nothing happens"?  Is it crashing, freezing, returning null, etc?

Comment: I am testing in fiddler. After the line of code where i get response, i am not able to debug further and couldn't see any error code.

Comment: Are both APIs running on the same application pool? Because they are then running in the same executable process, the debugger may be trying to step into the other API. Try putting breakpoints on string `responseString` and `string error` and hit F5 instead of stepping through.

Comment: The api where i have put the breakpoint is running in local iisexress from VS. The other api is hosted in IIS.

Comment: in VS, can you check `response.Content` before that liner where it stops